# How to use any kind of agent-capabilitie in task custom condition?

Tags: azure-devops

How can i use any kind of (user-defined or system-defined) capablity in custom conditions?

I've added a "User-defined capabilities" to one of my agents and called it "Agent.HasVsTest2019" with value "true".

And added a custom condition to a task and it's not working.

```
and(always(), eq(variables['Agent.HasVsTest2019'], 'true'))
```

expanded to (i didn't expect an evaluated value of Null):

```
and(always(), eq(Null, 'true'))
```

What's working though is:

```
and(always(), eq(variables['Agent.Name'], 'my_fancy_agent'))
```

expanded to:

```
and(always(), eq('my_fancy_agent', 'my_fancy_agent'))
```

Comment: Has this problem been resolved? It's not complex to set the user-defined capabilities as the condition. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) or keep posting if met any other problems during the process.

Comment: @[mb5079](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12473216/mbb5079) Both answers are helpful. Yours complents the answer of [kontekst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6334351/kontekst) nicely. So i picked the more helpful answer now.

Comment: Agent capabilities, both predefined and user, are checked in the "demands" section of the yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build pipeline you can use capabilities to specify which agent will run your pipeline specyfing in "demands" which capabilities are required by agent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

In release pipeline you can specify demands for each job

[image]

You can use Agent.Name because it is already predefined variable and is always accessible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables

I don't suppose that agent capabilities are mapped to variables. There is no information about feature like this in documentation.

Comment: This is for the entire job and not for tasks

Answer (score 1):

> And added a custom condition to a task and it's not working.
>
> `and(always(), eq(variables['Agent.HasVsTest2019'], 'true'))`
>
> expanded to (i didn't expect an evaluated value of Null):
>
> `and(always(), eq(Null, 'true'))`

This is because the variable 'Agent.HasVsTest2017' is neither a [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) (such as Agent.Name) nor a custom one in your pipeline like below one:

[image]

And the condition in task for this variable should be:

[image]

If you want to set Agent User-defined capabilities and theie values as the conditions, you need to set it in the pipeline agent job properties with the equals operater:

[image]

[image]